# Override wildcard selector for a particular div

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How can i remove a wildcard `*` from a specific div?

For example, in my css i have this

```
* {
      -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
      -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
      box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

I don't want for a specific div and his content don't having this class (wildcard).

Already tried with `box-sizing: content-box !important` but without success.

How can i accomplish this?

Comment: You have to redefine the default properties for :
`-moz-box-sizing`, `-webkit-box-sizing` and `box-sizing`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using only `box-sizing` which is a general property, which may not support the older browsers, or even the new ones, and hence, it would fail, using `*` has least preference, you can easily override it, by using a `class` or even a simple *element selector*

```
.one {
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/MNHMq/)

---

As you see [here](http://caniuse.com/css3-boxsizing), Firefox to be specific, still requires the `-moz` prefix for `box-sizing` property, and if you might be testing in Firefox, it fails for you, but it will apply `border-box` as you are using the prefixed version in your universal selector. Though you are using `content-box` as a value, it will be simply ignored as Firefox will deem the `box-sizing` property as invalid, and will simply skip to next property, hence, you don't need `!important`, you can use a specific selector, infact any selector, is more specific than `*` selector.